# Разница между sharecompat.intentbuilder vs action_send

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем разница? я сейчас новичок в андройде и увидел два метода для шейра текста к примеру через:

```
    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
            .setType("text/plain")
            .setText("Hello world")
            .getIntent();
```

и второй метод через:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textMessage);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем разница?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле различия только в удобстве. `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder` предоставляет вам удобный интерфейс создания `intent`-a.
Если заглянете в исходники `IntentBuilder` то в конструкторе увидите следующее:

```
private IntentBuilder(Activity launchingActivity) {
    mActivity = launchingActivity;
    mIntent = new Intent().setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    mIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, launchingActivity.getPackageName());
    mIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CALLING_ACTIVITY, launchingActivity.getComponentName());
    mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
}
```

В ходе работы с классом вы устанавливаете флаги `intent`-a. Для примера `setType`:

```
public IntentBuilder setType(String mimeType) {
            mIntent.setType(mimeType);
            return this;
        }
```

И в результате возвращаете уже готовый `intent` с помощью `getIntent()`.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо большое за ответ, так и думал)